# How can I provide Text Suggestions via VBA when user selects cell on in Excel Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, excel-2010

My company has a rather large import template that I've created an Add-In for which has a few useful shortcut tools and procedures that we user often.

**What I'd like to do:**
I would like to add an Intellisense-like feature that would work only when users select cells in four particular columns (BF, BG, CS, and CT) while working in the worksheet (not vbe).

**I want to mimic something like this:**
[image: Intellisense]

**More Specifically:**
When a cell is selected in any of the four columns I would like to provide suggestions in a dropdown list based on data that is entered throughout the worksheet in other columns.

When a user clicks into a blank cell:

1. They're given a list of values to choose from
2. Once they choose that value it is added to the cell and a colon is tacked onto the end of it
3. Still in the same cell I'd want the dropdown list to repopulate according to what the user first chose and present the new values.(The list would be smaller than the first list since their first value narrows down the choices)
4. Once the user chooses the second value it would be tacked onto the end of the value in the cell along with another colon.
5. Finally, the dropdown list would repopulate again according to what the user chose and present them with the last set of values (The list would be smaller than the first and second list since those values narrow down the choices), which they choose and are then finished filling out the cell

**An Example:**
In Columns V, W, and X are the values
Imprint Option|Single Option 1|Premium Custom Colors Available at Additional Cost. Call for Quote.
Respectively.

1. When the user clicks a cell in column BF they're presented first with a dropdown list that would include "Imprint Option" along with other choices found in Column V.
2. If they chose "Imprint Option" then "Imprint Option:" is entered into the current cell and the list repopulates with values found in Column W to the right of "Imprint Option" (meaning in this case only "Single Option 1" would be listed)
3. When the user selects "Single Option 1" the cell value is now "Imprint Option:Single Option 1:" and the list now only shows the value "Premium Custom Colors Available at Additional Cost. Call for Quote."
4. When the user selects this value the cell value is complete, showing "Imprint Option:Single Option 1:Premium Custom Colors Available at Additional Cost. Call for Quote.", and no list is shown

This is only a very simple example because obviously there will be more than one value in the list after it repopulates both times.

**My idea/thoughts:**
My thought was maybe this is possible by using a Combo Box without the dropdown arrow showing to recreate the dropdown list, but I'm not sure how or if this method could work with this because the values need to repopulate and there will be a value in the cell after the first round of value and I figured that would be overwritten. The only restriction I have is I have to create this on-the-fly. I won't be able to drag the controls onto the worksheet beforehand and to avoid any further performance hindering I only want to do it one cell at a time as they're selected.

**So, finally my questions:**

1. Is this possible to recreate?

   - If so, how should I go about it? (even if the method is complicated I'm open to hearing how)
2. If this isn't possible, could you suggest a way I could do something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually many ways of achieving this and probably some automations that are close to what you want. If you'd like to go down the road of making your own one, then I'd use a `UserForm` which contained just a `ListBox`.

There are APIs to show the `UserForm` next to the cell you selected and to remove the border from your `UserForm` so that it looks more like intellisense. You'd probably also want to handle some auto-sizing of the `ListBox`. I'll leave all of that to you, but a rudimentary version would look like this:

[image]

The basic idea would be that you create a database of items at their appropriate levels and then re-populate the `ListBox` with the appropriate array whenever a level index has changed. I'd do my database in XML but you could do it however you wished.

The code below is something to get you started but you'd want to expand it to deal with all the possible user activities, such as wanting to exit, changing their mind, deleting, etc.

**Step 1**: create a `UserForm` which has just one `ListBox` on it and make sure the `MultiSelect` property is set to single. In the example below I called the `UserForm` *IntelliSense* and the `ListBox` *lboxOptions*.

**Step 2**: this is the skeleton code behind for the userform

```
Option Explicit
Private mItems() As String
Private mSubItems1() As String
Private mSubItems2() As String
Private mSubItems3() As String
Private mSubItems4() As String
Private mIndex As Integer
Private mCell As Range

Private Property Let Index(val As Integer)
    mIndex = val
    Select Case val
        Case 0: lboxOptions.List = mItems
        Case 1: lboxOptions.List = mSubItems1
        Case 2: lboxOptions.List = mSubItems2
        Case 3: lboxOptions.List = mSubItems3
        Case 4: lboxOptions.List = mSubItems4
    End Select
End Property

Private Sub HandleItemSelected()
    Dim i As Integer

    'Identify the selected item
    For i = 0 To lboxOptions.ListCount - 1
        If lboxOptions.Selected(i) Then
            If mIndex = 0 Then
                'Write to the cell and add a full stop
                mCell.Value = lboxOptions.List(i) & "."
                'Trigger the next level of dropdown
                Index = i + 1
            Else
                'Write to the cell and close the window
                mCell.Value = mCell.Value & lboxOptions.List(i)
                Me.Hide
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub lboxOptions_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    'Trap the return key event as if 'selected'
    If KeyAscii = vbKeyReturn Then
        HandleItemSelected
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub lboxOptions_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    'Trap the click event as if 'selected'
    HandleItemSelected
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    'Reset the list and store the target cell
    Set mCell = Selection
    Index = 0
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'Define the arrays of selections.
    'I'd probably create an XML for this and read it into some arrays here.
    Const items As String = "Cake|IceCream|Pasta|Chips"
    Const subs1 As String = "Eggs|Flour|Butter|Sugar|Bake"
    Const subs2 As String = "Milk|Eggs|Sugar|Freeze"
    Const subs3 As String = "Eggs|Flour|Boil"
    Const subs4 As String = "Potatoes|Oil|Fry"

    mItems = Split(items, "|")
    mSubItems1 = Split(subs1, "|")
    mSubItems2 = Split(subs2, "|")
    mSubItems3 = Split(subs3, "|")
    mSubItems4 = Split(subs4, "|")
End Sub
```

**Step 3**: enter this code in your `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const DESIRED_ADDRESS As String = "A:A, C:C, E:E"
    Dim desired As Range

    IntelliSense.Hide

    'Check if just one cell has been selected
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        'Check if target cell is one that we want
        Set desired = Me.Range(DESIRED_ADDRESS)
        If Not Intersect(Target, desired) Is Nothing Then
            'Check that target cell is blank
            If Len(Target.Value) = 0 Then
                'All criteria met so show 'IntelliSense'
                IntelliSense.Show False
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This is very impressive, creative, and useful! It appears to be exactly what I need. Just a few questions first though. Why would I be pasting the same thing for both the UserForm and `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event? Could you help clarify why both codes need to be the same, is it something to do with passing the values? Also, was there meant to be a step between 2 and 4 or was that just a typo?

Comment: It's because I'm a muppet and have put the wrong code in - hang on and I'll change it.

Comment: Perfect! This is a great piece of work, thank you so much for providing such a useful sample!

Answer (score 1):

Excel has some built-in features that you may be able to adapt:

1. insert a `Comment` - triggered by simply mouse-over
2. insert a `Data Validation` message - triggered by clicking in the cell
3. insert a `Data Validation` pull-down - to direct a selection from a known list
4. use a worksheet event macro to display a UserForm

From your detailed requirements description, I would pick option **4**

Comment: A UserForm wouldn't work in my situation unfortunately unless there were a way to make one that's very small and popped up next to each cell when the cell was clicked. Would it be possible to do multiple Data validation rules with a pull down? Would it be able to repopulate?

Answer (score 0):

What your describing can be done using data validation. Here is an article that outlines the process: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/211485. This may not be exactly what your looking for as you would end up with multiple cells with the different available options that are selected by the user. You could then use a concatenate formula to bring all of the selections together into one cell. Some one else may have a better way of doing this in VBA, but this was my first thought when I read your post. I hope this is some help.